# Any way to not process some object in Away3D Lite?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, 3d, papervision3d, away3d

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid processing some objects in a away3DLite scene. The problem is that I Have a scene with a lot of spheres, some of them are not visible ( out of camera range ) and I would like not to processing them.

Maybe Away3D automatically does that.

Maybe visible = false can help

Any good tutorials on Away3d optimizing BTW???

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awa3D does that automagically. They call it culling. It does not render objects behind the camera, and out of camera range. (It does however have to calculate if they are in the camera range each frame)

There are some objects you can use for faraway spheres that are less costly, like billboards and Sprite2D. If your object does not need to show more than one side, theses are an ideal choice.